# Relationships always return as empty on Spring Data Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

Spring boot version: 2.4.6

I have a query like to find users by country:

```
@Query("MATCH (u:User)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:Country) " +
        "WHERE c.countryCode = $country " +
        "WITH u " +
        "MATCH (u)-[p:HAS_FRIENDS]->(:User) " +
        "RETURN u, collect(p)")
List<User> findByCountry(@Param("country") String country);
```

To add a new friend:

```
@Query("CREATE (u:User {name: $friendName}) " +
        "WITH u " +
        "MATCH (n:User) WHERE ID(n) = $userId " +
        "WITH u,n " +
        "CREATE (n)-[:HAS_FRIENDS]->(u) " +
        "RETURN n")
User addFriendRelation(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("friendName") String friendName);
```

I have a node like:

```
@Data //Getter,Setter, ToString, Equals...
@NoArgsConstructor // empty constructor
@Node
public class User
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Property
    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = "HAS_FRIENDS") // it can be also converted to an entity.
    private List<User> friends;

    //User lives in these countries...
    @Relationship(type = LivesInRelation.TYPE)
    private LivesInRelation livesIn;

    public User(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And to test it:

```
@Test
public void testFindByCountry()
{
    User user = new User("Bob");
    user.setLivesIn(new LivesInRelation(user, new Country("US"), LocalDateTime.of(2000, 1, 1, 1, 1)));
    User usedDB = userRepository.saveUser(user);
    userService.userRepository(usedDB.getId(), "Marry");

    List<User> userListByCountry = userRepository.findByCountry("US");

    assertThat(userListByCountry).hasSize(1);
    assertThat(userListByCountry.get(0).getFriends()).hasSize(1); //Doesn't work
    assertThat(userListByCountry.get(0).getName()).isEqualTo("Bob");
}
```

I've implemented like that. Queries work on neo4j-browser like a charm. But on spring-boot, they are not.
So how can I return Node with relationships? Is there any suggestion?

Solution:

```
@Query("MATCH (u:User)-[r:LIVES_IN]->(c:Country) " +
            "WHERE c.countryCode = $country " +
            "WITH u " +
            "MATCH (u)-[p:HAS_FRIENDS]->(x:User) " +
            "RETURN u, collect(p), collect(x)")
    List<User> findByCountry(@Param("country") String country);
```

More detail: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2260

Comment: Cross post https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/issues/2260